# Golden-haired comic book villain who could perform mass-hypnosis with his voice

Tags: comics, character-identification

I'm looking for a comic book story about a golden-haired villain who could perform mass-hypnosis with his voice. He wore a suit and tried to get a crowd to attack a government building. Our heroes stopped him, maybe by unmasking him? It was definitely from the 80s.

Comment: Which heroes stopped him?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the character you had in mind, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you're thinking of the New God, **[Glorious Godfrey](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Glorious_Godfrey_(New_Earth))**...?

> A subpar athlete and hand-to-hand combatant, Glorious Godfrey's greatest gifts are his overwhelming speaking voice and his extraordinary powers of persuasion.
>
> [image: Who's Who: The Definitive Directory of the DC Universe #9, page 11]
>
> <sub>*[Who's Who: The Definitive Directory of the DC Universe #9](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Who%27s_Who:_The_Definitive_Directory_of_the_DC_Universe_Vol_1_9)* (November, 1985)</sub>

In the *[Legends](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Legends_Vol_1)* miniseries (1986-1987), Darkseid sent Godfrey to Earth in the guise of 'G. Gordon Godfrey' to whip up anti-superhero sentiment among the general public. This involved Godfrey actively inciting people to overthrow the US government at one point.

> GLORIOUS GODFREY: A government that does not represent its people does not serve its people! Such an evil government must be overthrown!
>
> [image: Legends #4, page 18]
>
> <sub>*[Legends #4](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Legends_Vol_1_4)* (February, 1987)</sub>

Various members of the Justice League (Superman, Batman, Wonder Woman, etc.) were involved in that story, although Godfrey effectively defeated himself in the end, when he unwisely put on Dr. Fate's helmet, which didn't take too kindly to him.

Comment: The comic is much funnier if you imagine him with Gilbert Godfrey's voice

Comment: Ronald Reagan made guest appearances in DC comics?  Huh.  I thought using real life political figures was more of a Marvel-thing.  (DC doesn't even like using real cities, hence Gotham and Metropolis, etc.)

Comment: @RobinClower - _Everything_ is funnier if you imagine it in Gilbert Godfrey's voice.

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman - They used Reagan's likeness, but I don't think they used his name at any point. He's just referred to as _"The President"_ or _"Mr. President"_.

Comment: A carrot-haired populist inciting a crowd to attack the US government? Too ridiculous; could never happen. :-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, Godfrey was defeated by a couple of kids who told him off and turned the crowd against him. Only then, out of desperation, did he put on Fate's helmet.